# php recursive function for array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have a multidimentional array (`MyArray`), and want to "linearize" it to a string. So I try with this recursive function:

```
function RecursiveFunction($TheArray){
    foreach($TheArray as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $RecursiveOutput.="(".$key.")";
            RecursiveFunction($value); //-->this does't seem to work
        } else {
            $RecursiveOutput.="(".$value.")";
        }
    }
    return $RecursiveOutput;
}
echo RecursiveFunction($MyArray);
```

However, I'm getting the keys from the first level of the array only: the recursive recall doesn't seem to work. Can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: You do not pick the return value of the inner function call, which you need to do.

Comment: You are returning `$RecursiveOutput` but you aren't catching the return value.

Comment: Try this `$RecursiveOutput .= "(".$key.")"."(".RecursiveFunction($value).")";`

Comment: Or  you  could pass the variable by reference?

Comment: @RisulIslam thats it! `$RecursiveOutput .= "(".$key.")"."(".RecursiveFunction($value).")";`. Post as an answer for accepting. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CMArg: Didn't you see my comment?

Comment: @1stthomas yes, and thanks a lot for answering. It only happens that Risul Islam wrote the code with the solution. I will also take a closer look at LinkinTED's comment....

Comment: @CMArg: Actually I wrote exactly the same as him but two minutes before him. He answered after you told him, he should.

Comment: @1stthomas ok, you're right. But after your comment I was indeed asking you "how I can do that?". I cancel that comment after Risul answer. Anyway, I don't think its a big deal. Those things happen all the time in this site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `$RecursiveOutput` but you aren't catching the return value. Try this

```
$RecursiveOutput .= "(". $key .")(". RecursiveFunction($value) .")";
```